# how to do pg_dump for a main partition table without related partition tables

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to do pg_dump with just main partition table but seeing the entire existing partitioned tables.

```
pg_dump -T ‘public.”2021”’  -s  -O -x master_database -h host -U user > master.sql
```

Comment: Well `-T public.2021` would exclude that table and include all other tables. If you want to include a specific table it is `-t` per [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: yeah I am aware of that hence used -T but it won't help me stop dumping indexes and partitioned tables of parent

Comment: You are going to need to update your question with a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve. At the moment the code you show and your description of what you want don't match.

Comment: Yes, this needs clarification. With a partitioned table, the table itself contains no rows at all, only the partitions do.